# What does VNC reflectors basically do?

Tags: vnc

I am confused about what vnc reflector does. From the documentation http://sourceforge.net/projects/vnc-reflector/ I got that it's proxysitting between real VNC server (a host) and a number of VNC clients.

My confusion is : 1. Does it make any changes to the coming stream from server 2. Does it make 1 connection with server to connect to many client or the connections are proportionate.

Documentation is not clear in this. If anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6):

The [VNC reflector](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vnc-reflector/) is designed to reduce CPU load on the VNC server or network traffic across a specific link (or both). The reflector acts like a single client to the VNC server, but it has enough knowledge of the protocol to act like a VNC server itself for multiple clients.

Use cases:

- VNC server is too slow to handle lots of VNC clients: run a VNC reflector on a separate machine so that the load of multiple clients is handled by that machine instead.
- Office with two locations: run VNC server in one office and a VNC reflector in the other office. Clients in the first office connect to the real server and clients in the other office connect to the reflector. This will greatly reduce the traffic on the link between the two offices. If the remote office doesn't have a super fast connection to the other office, then without the reflector the remote office will have terrible performance.

Comment: The most helpful documentation is its [README](https://sourceforge.net/p/vnc-reflector/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/reflector/README) file.